# read pdf from server write to new pdf file

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

In this code I am trying to hit a server to get the pdf files, and read those pdf files and trying to write them into a new pdf file.

```
URL vConcreteUrl = new URL(Globals.c_Retrieve_Url_Equals.replace("{BD_ID}", vBdId));
PDDocument p = PDDocument.load(vConcreteUrl.openStream());
PDDocument c = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = p.getPage(1);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(p, page);
contentStream.beginText();
String text = vBdId;
contentStream.showText(vBdId);
contentStream.endText();
System.out.println("content added");
contentStream.close();
p.save(new File("U:/pdf" + vBdId + ".pdf"));

p.close();
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1119)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2017)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1988)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:269)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1143)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1040)
at com.ikea.stebu.od.util.pdf.DownloadPDFFromOndemand.execute
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: The is an end-of-file error while parsing the pdf file header. That sounds like an empty stream.

Comment: Did the comment by mkl help or not?